# Synonym for "dream life"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I have been unable to find a good word (or 2-word phrase) to convey the idea of "dream life", by which I mean "the possible future state of my life in which I experience even more fulfillment, health, and joy".

One of the reasons I'd like to discover a good synonym is for a replacement of the occupational title of "Personal Dream Life Coach".

I'm obviously not referring to dreams had when sleeping but instead mean "ideals" or "ambitions" or "hopes".

Comment: "Fulfillment" - which you already have in the description - seems like a reasonable choice.

Comment: _desired future_?

Answer (score 2):

Utopian Lifestyle could possibly work.

Answer (score 1):

***A word or short phrase for the possible future state of one's life***

If I read the implications of your question correctly, you seek a distinctive replacement for the rather generic title, "Personal Dream Life Coach." My response is directed toward a title that is more unique and personal. Additionally, because I realize that the occupation involves (among other things) enhancing a client's ability to visualize (*via* techniques like directed imagination, conscious dreaming, etc.) in order to actualize an ideal, fulfilling future life, I've linked some philosophical, metaphysical, and spiritual concepts related to IMMINENCE for you to consider, if you are so inclined.

> **A**: **Imminent** *adjective* (*imminent* life guide or coach)
>
> **1** About to happen;
>   ‘there was speculation that a ceasefire was *imminent’*
>
> **Synonyms**:
>   impending, at hand, close, near, approaching, fast approaching, coming, forthcoming, on the way, about to happen, upon us, in store, in the offing, in the pipeline, on the horizon, in the air, in the wind, brewing, looming, looming large; 
>   threatening, menacing; expected, anticipated.

You will notice that "*imminent*" carries positive, neutral, and negative connotations (apparent in the above synonyms) highly dependent upon context.

> See **Imminent** @ [**Oxford Dictionary**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/imminent)

Additionally, the word as "Imminence" has deep philosophical, metaphysical, and spiritual articulations you can peruse @ [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanence)

> **B**: **Proximate** *adjective* (*proximate* life guide or coach) coming or happening immediately before or after something in a way that shows a very close and direct relationship.
>
> **1**: immediately preceding or following (as in a chain of events, causes, or effects)
>
> **2** *a*: very near: Close
>
> *b*: soon forthcoming : Imminent
>
> **Synonyms**: approaching, coming, imminent, impending, nearing, oncoming, pending, forthcoming, upcoming
>
> See **Proximate** @ [**Merriam-Webster** *online*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proximate?show=0&t=1422169653)

Comment: Would the terms your are suggesting be possible synonyms for 'dream life'?

Comment: No @Josh61 - rather, I directed my answer toward the other aspect of the OP's query--"'dream life,' by which I mean '*the possible future state of my life*...'"

Comment: @Josh61 - can you see what I was aiming at?

Comment: Yes, not what is being  asked actually. Maybe OP find it useful.

Comment: @Josh61 - yes, well, it's partially asked. If I read the implications of the query correctly, OP seeks a distinctive replacement for the rather ubiquitous and altogether generic title, "Personal Dream Life Coach." The occupation involves among other things enhancing their client's ability to visualize, *via* techniques like directed imagination, an ideal and fulfilling future life. My response is directed toward that titular distinctiveness and includes some   philosophical, metaphysical, and spiritual concepts related to IMMINENCE for OP to 'kick around.' Am I too far afield, IYO?

Comment: @LittleEva, thank you for putting so much thought into this.  I appreciate this angle.  I haven't yet figured out how to make it fit/work just right, but I'll keep pondering.